# Convert a byte array which is a zip file back into a zip file

Tags: c#, gitlab, zip, .net-4.5

I am downloading a zip file that is stored in GitLab using below code:

```
   using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler())
    {
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://my.gitlab.space/api/v4/projects/100/packages/generic/mypackage/1.0.0.0/myZipFile.zip");

            request.Headers.Add("PRIVATE-TOKEN", "myTokenHere");

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseBody);
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\myZipFile.zip", data);
        }
   }
```

This should be the equivalent to the following curl command:

> curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: myTokenHere"
> "https://my.gitlab.space/api/v4/projects/100/packages/generic/mypackage/1.0.0.0/myZipFile.zip"
> --output myZipFile.zip

Above code and also the curl command are working ok, except that i cannot convert the byte array data into a zip file in my local disk. By default, the byte array is already a zip file.

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Readup on `HttpClient`. Though it implements `IDisposable`, it's not intended to disposed after every use (like, say, a `SqlConnection`)

Comment: @Flydog57 why is HttpClient not intended to be disposed on every use? Could you explain more in details?

Comment: Search for HttpClient (hint: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient). Look at _Remarks_ and particularly _Instancing_. There's an internet out there that does a much better job of explaining than I can

Comment: @Flydog57in my special case i am going to use only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ReadAsByteArrayAsync` instead of `ReadAsStringAsync`. You want to read the content directly as the file's bytes.

```
byte[] data = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
```

Comment: For the future, make sure you keep an eye on the Content-Type header of the response that the API documentation says the endpoint gives you. "AsString" is good for application/json and text/plain. "AsByteArray" should be used for binary formats, because you don't need to deal with encoding.

Comment: thank you, i will take it into account for the future.

Comment: Why not just copy the response stream straight to the file

Comment: @Charlieface TBH I didn't think of that. I focused on the singular erroring line. I like your suggestion better.

Answer (score 3):

Your primary issue is you are reading the data as a string. You can read it as bytes, but it's more efficient to just copy the response stream straight to a file.

Other issues:

- Don't create a new handler every time, this can cause socket exhaustion. Instead use a `static HttpClient`
- Don't use `ServicePointManager` as it sets the settings across the whole app. Use the client instead.
- Don't set the `SecurityProtocol` manually. Rely on the operating system to select the best protocol.
  You only need to set it manually if you are using .NET 4.5, which is now completely out of support and should be upgraded ASAP.
- Various objects need disposing

```cs
static HttpClient _client = new
{
    DefaultRequestHeaders = 
    {
        ExpectContinue = true,
    },
};
```

```cs
using HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://my.gitlab.space/api/v4/projects/100/packages/generic/mypackage/1.0.0.0/myZipFile.zip");

request.Headers.Add("PRIVATE-TOKEN", "myTokenHere");

using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
using var file = File.OpenWrite(@"D:\myZipFile.zip");
using var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
await stream.CopyToAsync(file);
```

Comment: not working line: using var stream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(), data);

Comment: if i don't use servicepointmanager then using your code an exception is thrown saying: {"The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."}

Comment: Sorry typo, fixed now. Which version of Windows and .NET do you have? Any recent version should work without setting the TLS version

Comment: i am using .NET 4.5 standard so this is the reason i need to use servicePointManager, and set the SecurityProtocol. There is not other way to do this in NET-4.5 as far as i know

Comment: Ah I see, yes. But 4.5 is heavily out of date and insecure now, you should upgrade pronto.

Comment: Yep, I know, but it is not feasible to update now in my case. But sooner in future for sure but not now ;) By the way, I have done what you say, i mean, just copy the response stream straight to a file.

Comment: regarding making static httpClient, i am only calling that piece of code exactly once per program execution so not need to make it static in my special case i guess.

Comment: Yes that is true